# Why loops in Remix IDE can only be write in a function?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

I tried to write a loop code without a function , but it gave an error[image: Error Image].

But after wrote it in a function, it worked. Why?

[image: Loop code in a function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart contracts, and more specifically anything written in solidity, can only be deployed on a blockchain, meaning they run on the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM). Every time processing power is used on the EVM, a gas fee must be paid. Any data processing or actions such as loops must be paid for with the gas fee. Because of this, these actions must be confined within a function so that they can be called and paid for.

If you could run a loop outside of a function/constructor, it would have no definition of where or when to run and therefore either never be used or cost infinite gas.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the `for` loop and other conditions into a function because it is only method to handle the data.

**You cannot use the conditions outside a function (or constructor)!**

Comment: Thanks for the  answer but I'm kind of confused about this statement ," it is only method to handle the data" . Why it's handling of data method is different unlike other programming languages. Kindly, can you explain it, because I'm new to solidity.

Comment: You can only handle the data in a function. Ex.: If you don't declare a function you cannot use foreach,if,for,while and other conditions necessary to iterate or set on a specific data. Example: In your case that you have described above, you cannot implement for loop because you haven't declare a function. For this reason, if you don't declare the function keyword you cannot set value in array index and you cannot increase count variable. This last operations need to handle the data.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Kerry99's answer;

1. This has nothing to do with Remix IDE, it is about Solidity language specification, solc compiler and little bit with design-oriented programming and tiny bit with evm
2. This is a design choice by solidity language, if you what you are asking is *why is it designed that way*, it is open to discussion. Executing code(loops,conditions and function calls) on the contract scope itself could be used for initializing variables, and we have something for that, `constructor`
   If the question is *why it started working after I wrapped it inside a function block*, dangling code(?) in your contract block was not syntactically okay to the compiler